# Are there currently any solar panels that are produced/built entirely with solar power/energy?

Tags: solar-power

The closely related 
[Are there types of solar panels that can be made completely locally and independent of fossil fuels?](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/questions/2535) Suggests that it is possible to make solar cells without fossil fuels.

I wondering if there are currently any solar panels on available commercially that are built (*including material acquisition*) entirely with solar power/energy?

Comment: Somewhere down the line a component will be made using fossil fuels. That's also the case with the answers in the question you link to. The copper is undoubtedly mined and melted using fossil fuels. So I'd say the answer is no.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, there aren't: fossil fuels penetrate the entire global economy, currently.

It's possible. It will be common in some years time (maybe as little as 10, maybe as much as 30, depending on when politicians and voters finally decide to get serious about mitigating catastrophic climate change), but it's not happening anywhere right now, partly because so many of the input materials are transported by fossil-fuelled vehicles.